# How to dynamically update the FusionChart Piecharts

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pie-chart, fusioncharts

Please can i know, how do we update the piechart shown in this example through the asp.net code.  http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/business/#election-results-india-2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe example has hardcoded values inside the Flash application.

The demo is basically showcasing drilldown feature.

If you are using ASP.NET to recreate this, steps are simple:

1. Create a .NET page (say in URL-A) that responses back XML (for FusionCharts Pie chart) based on a query sent to it (can connect to database etc. in this code)
2. Create a map in another page using FusionMaps and put link to each state (entity) in the map. The link should call a javascript function pass some unique id (may be of the state)
3. Create a pie chart using FusionCharts rendered in the page with blank data (ready to be updated when a state in the map is clicked).
4. The JavaScript function will build a URL-B (URL-A + the id of the state passed as query string)
5. The JavaScript will pass the URL-B to the pie chart and ask it to update its data from the URL-B.

There is no extra requirement of AJAX and AJAX controls. The chart will internally take care of this.